# Random, occasional file access problem, for a simple code

Tags: python

Every once in a while the code

```
with open(self.filename,'w') as fp:
    json.dump(self.settings, fp)
```

throws an error

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'settings.json'
```

The file is there, its name doesn't have any problematic characters, there is no multithreading, and the exception only happens less than 1% of the times this code runs.

I catch the exception and try again, and everything is good (I have a loop that can try a maximum of 5 times, but one additional try seems to be enough).

I cannot explain this behavior... and it feels like I am missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file you are reading from large?

Comment: Does the error happen in the `open` or the `json.dump`?

Comment: @kconsiglio seems they are writing to a file? But are you sure it is fully closed when you jump in the location?

Comment: what is the underlying storage? regular filesystem on local disk or maybe something networked?

Comment: To answer the questions here: 
1. the file is very small, around 2 kilobytes.
2. the error happens in the ```open``` statement
3. why wouldn't the file be fully closed? it is only written to are read from using short ```with``` statements
4. regular file system on HD

Comment: How many total files would you likely have open at one time in this process and/or what are the `ulimit` settings for the user running this code?

Comment: Only one file... this one, and it is usually closed, except for brief moments where it is accessed with a ```with``` statement such as the one above. I did not put any limit

Comment: Well... I didn't think about it... but the program is in a folder that is in dropbox :/... now my bet is that this is the problem. what do you think? Dropbox opening the file and preventing me from doing so?